# Selenium testing: webdriver.wait call promise multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, promise, selenium-chromedriver

for testing purposes, I am use selenuim chromedriver, nodejs and mocha...

I am in a bit of pickle now:

- `driver.wait` works beautifully with `until`
- I have a promise, let's call it `promiseA`, this takes a `webdriver` and css classsName, does some calculation returns boolean. this works fine.
- the pickle is combining `webdriver.wait` and `promiseA`, I want the wait function to repeatedly(*multiple times*) check the resolve of `promiseA` till timeout is reached or boolean returned is true, but right now, it stops at the first resolve, and that obviously being false, breaks my test.

the sample code

```
webdriver.wait(promiseA(webdriver, 'cssClass'), 5000)
    .then(...
```

my only back-up which works is, but I find it very ugly and inefficient:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    promiseA(webdriver, 'cssClass')
        .then(function(bool)...
...
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

made a temp fix, still waiting for a cleaner solution:

```
function waiter(promise, argList,waitTime){
    var deffered = Driver.promise.defer(),  
        wt = waitTime || 20,
        pCall = function(){
                        promise.apply(promise, argList).then(pThen, pCatch);
                    },
        pThen = function(data){
                    if(data){
                        deffered.fulfill(true);
                    }else{
                        setTimeout(pCall, wt);
                    }
                },  
        pCatch = function(err){
                    setTimeout(pCall, wt);
                };  

    pCall();    
    return deffered.promise;
}
```

usage:

```
...
button.click()        
    .then(function(){
        var promise = waiter(promiseA, [arg1, arg2, arg3] );
        return driver1.wait(promise, 5000); // keep checking till five seconds, 
    }).then(...
```